# How to maintain position and size of dialog window after logout and then login?

Tags: position, size, jquery-ui-dialog

I call a new dialog window like this:

```
$("#modalSeznam").load('./safe/kalkulace_seznamPotreb.php?k_polozka=<?echo $k_polozka;?>').dialog({modal:false, title:'Seznam všech potřeb', width:"auto", height:"auto"});
```

What I need: If I will logout and then login back, I want this dialog window to open on the same position and with same size as I left it before the logout... Is there any way to do this? Please help, I´ll be happy for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ['position' option](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) of dialog() method?

Comment: I tried that, but maybe its not enough...Shouldn´t I use some session or something like that?